# using mod_rewrite with two variables in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hi ive set up a rewrite and it works perfectly, here it is

```
RewriteRule ^polls-([0-9]+)\.html$ poll.php?poll_id=$1
```

This would allow an URL like polls-1.html instead of poll.php?poll_id=1.

My problem is this; i have another variable to view results, this is what i would usually call - poll.php?poll_id=1&showResults=1

How do i set up a rule where i can use some thing like: polls-1/results-1.html ?? Ive searched the net for a while but cant find anything

Answer (score 1):

Add another Rule, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^polls-([0-9]+)\/results\.html$ poll.php?poll_id=$1&showResults=1
```

It will redirect `polls-1/results.html` to `poll.php?poll_id=1&showResults=1`

Comment: it was a good answer and works to a certain extent. However it fails to load any CSS or JS on the results pages